# how to move next cursor on next row in html table using java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hi i have HTML table text fields i want to move next row when I click on add button please guide me how to do this see image below

Problem
Currently the new row is a clone, so the elements would have the same name for the new row, as it would for the original row. Resulting in duplicates of the selSupplierName field.

Symptom
When JQuery then finds the field based on the name selSupplierName, it would select the first instance, and not the new rows' bersion of the selSupplierName.

[image: table]

and here is my code

```
 <head>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui- 
 lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .highlight_row {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

</head>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10" style="margin:auto">
    <table class="styled-table" id="item-list">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:25%">
            <col style="width:25%">
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:10%">

        </colgroup>
        <thead style="height:40px;font-size:12px;font- 
      weight:bold">
            <tr>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Store Name</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Product 
       Name</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Unit</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Qty</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Price</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Total</th>
                <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           
            <tr class="po-item" data-id="">
              
                <td class="align-middle p-1">
    <select name="selSupplierName" 
   id="selSupplierName" onkeypress="return 
   pressEnter('ProductName')" tabindex="3" class="form-control 
    js-example-basic-single">
                        <option value="">Select Supplier</option>
                        @{
                        foreach (string name in 
      ViewBag.SupplierList)
                        {
                        <option value="@name">@name</option>
                        }
                        }


                    </select>

                </td>
                <td class="align-middle p-1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]">
                    <input type="text" id="ProductName" onkeypress="return pressEnter('qty')" class="form-control text-box single-line" required />
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle p-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="unit[]"  />
                </td>

                <td class="align-middle p-0 text-center">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-box single-line" onkeypress="return pressEnter('unit_price')" step="any" id="qty" name="qty[]" />
                </td>
                
               
                <td class="align-middle p-1">
                    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control text-box single-line" onkeypress="return pressEnter('add_row')" id="unit_price" name="unit_price[]"  />
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle p-1">
                    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="total-price[]" />
                </td>
             
                <td class="align-middle p-1 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn btn-sm btn-flat btn-primary py-0 mx-1" type="button"   id="add_row"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0" type="button" onclick="rem_item($(this))"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </td>
                 
                 
            </tr>
           
                    </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="bg-lightblue">
            <tr>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="5">Total</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" id="sub_total">0</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6">
                    Discount (%)
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="discount_percentage" class="border-light text-right">
                </th>
                <th class="p-1"><input type="text" class="w-100 border-0 text-right" readonly /></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6">
                    Tax Inclusive (%)
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="tax_percentage" class="border-light text-right">
                </th>
                <th class="p-1"><input type="text" class="w-100 border-0 text-right" readonly /> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="5">Total</th>
                <th class="p-1 text-right" id="total">0</th>
            </tr>
          
        </tfoot>
    </table>
   
    </div>
    </div>


   <table class="styled-table" id="item-clone" 
 style="margin:auto;display:none;width:auto" >
  <tr class="po-item" data-id="">
    <td class="align-middle p-1">
   <select name="selSupplierName" id="selSupplierName" 
   onkeypress="return pressEnter('BiltyNo')" tabindex="3" 
   class="form-control js-example-basic-single">
            <option value="">Select Supplier</option>
            @{
            foreach (string name in ViewBag.SupplierList)
            {
            <option value="@name">@name</option>
            }
            }


        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle p-1">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ProductName" onkeypress="return pressEnter()" required />
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle p-1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="unit[]" />
    </td>

    <td class="align-middle p-0 text-center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-box single-line" step="any" name="qty[]" />
    </td>
    
    
    <td class="align-middle p-1">
        <input type="number"   class="form-control text-box single-line" name="unit_price[]" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle p-1">
        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control text-box single-line" name="total-price[]" />
    </td>

    <td class="align-middle p-1 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn btn-sm btn-flat btn-primary py-0 mx-1" onclick="add_row()"  type="button" id="add_row"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0" type="button" onclick="rem_item($(this))"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

    </td>
    <td class="align-middle p-1 text-center">

    </td>
```

```
<script>

function pressEnter(nextInput) {

    // Key Code for ENTER = 13
    //if ((event.keyCode == 13)) {

    //    document.getElementById(nextInput).focus({ preventScroll: false });
    //}
}

function rem_item(_this) {
    _this.closest('tr').remove()
}

function calculate() {
    var _total = 0
  
    $('.po-item').each(function () {
        var row_total = 0;
        var qty = $(this).find("[name='qty[]']").val()
        var unit_price = $(this).find("[name='unit_price[]']").val()
        
        if (qty > 0 && unit_price > 0) {
            row_total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(unit_price)
           
        }
        $(this).find("[name='total-price[]']").val((row_total))
      
       
    })
   
}

//$('#add_row').click(function () {
//    var tr = $('#item-clone tr').clone()
//    $('#item-list tbody').append(tr)
//    //_autocomplete(tr)
//    tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress', function (e) {
//        calculate()
//    })
//        $("#selSupplierName").focus();
//})

$('#add_row').click(function () {

    // Get the count of rows.
    var counter = $('.my-row-class').length;

    // Your clone functionality.
    var tr = $('#item-clone tr').clone();

    // Add a class to it.
    tr.addClass("my-row-class");

    // Define the new ID (Not using iterpolation on purpose). 
    var newId = "row" + counter;
    tr.attr('id', newId);
     
    // Add it to the table body.
    $('#item-list tbody').append(tr);

    // Your calc function.
    tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress', function (e) {
        calculate();
    });

    alert(newId);
    // Select based on the composite id.
   // $("#selSupplierName").find('input:last').focus();

    $(newId + " #selSupplierName").focus();
})

function add_row()
{
    $('#add_row').trigger('click')
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  
    if ($('#item-list .po-item').length > 0) {
        $('#item-list .po-item').each(function () {
            var tr = $(this)
          //  _autocomplete(tr)
            tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress', function (e) {
                calculate()
            })
            //$('#item-list tfoot').find('[name="discount_percentage"],[name="tax_percentage"]').on('input keypress', function (e) {
            //    calculate()
            //})
            tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').trigger('keypress')
        })
    } else {
        $('#add_row').trigger('click')
    }
    $('.select2').select2({ placeholder: "Please Select here", width: "relative" })



})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+focus+next+field+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Just checking, do you want a new row added, or inserted in-between? With some more context, I am sure we can help quickly.

Comment: @DanielZA when I click on add button new row is added and want to focus on selSupplierName field newly added row..see my code this code works always focus on first row selSupplierName field

Comment: The issue would be that adding a new line, technically creates a new row with the same elements. So you would theoretically have a duplicate `selSupplierName`.

Comment: The recommended solution would be to create a dynamic ID for the row, and then select the element as a child of the row added. 

For your example, this is the case as the `tr` is a literal clone of the row. So by adding an ID property you would be able to select the correct instance of the object you want to focus on.

Comment: @DanielZA yes maybe please help me  I m new in html and java script

Comment: @stevejhones I have added some potential fixes for you below, I cannot test them as I do not have your full code. But I hope it steers you in the right direction. It should at least paint a picture of why it is happening, and allow you to come up with an even better fix yourself in the long run.

Comment: @DanielZA i have post all my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

Currently the new row is a clone, so the elements would have the same name for the new row, as it would for the original row. Resulting in duplicates of the `selSupplierName` field.

#### Symptom

When JQuery then finds the field based on the name `selSupplierName`, it would select the first instance, and not the new rows' bersion of the `selSupplierName`.

#### Recommendations

The proper solution would be adding an ID to the cloned row (`tr`), as this would would make finding the newly created row's child also named `selSupplierName` easy.

The quick fix would be to select the last instance of `selSupplierName`, as that is where the new row should technically be residing.

#### Quick Example of Proposed Fix

```js
$('#add_row').click(function () {

    // Get the count of rows.
    var counter = $('.my-row-class').size();
   
    // Your clone functionality.
    var tr = $('#item-clone tr').clone();

    // Add a class to it.
    tr.addClass( "my-row-class" );

    // Define the new ID (Not using iterpolation on purpose). 
    var newId = "row" + counter;
    tr.attr('id') = `row`;

    // Add it to the table body.
    $('#item-list tbody').append(tr);

    // Your calc function.
    tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress', function (e) {
        calculate();
    });

    // Select based on the composite id.
    $(newId + " #selSupplierName").focus();
})
```

I believe something like this should work in your solution, however as I don't have all your relevant code testing this would be a pain.

#### Quick Example of the potential Quick Fix

```js
// Select the last instance of the element.
$("#selSupplierName").last().focus();
```

Comment: No problem, as long as it helps.

Comment: not working let post whole code please check I update my question now